# mouse, keyboard or monitor randomly not working on 5% of win 7 boots

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, troubleshooting, dvi

Sometimes (e.g 5%) I boot the computer and either the mouse (usb), or the keyboard (usb), or the monitor (dvi) will not work although the devices are powered. Nothing different is been done while shuting down (before the boot) or while booting. The pattern is totally random. The solution is always to unplug the offending device (mouse, keyboard or monitor) for 2 seconds and then replug. It then immediatelly works.

I run Win 7 Pro SP1 and my computer is a 2 years old with no viruses or cracked software installed. A CPU-Z dump of my current setup can be found at http://pastebin.com/6irDKXfv

Any ideas on where should I look at?

Comment: Could be a failing motherboard or maybe an out-of-date BIOS or drivers. Have you tried updating the BIOS, Motherboard Chipset driver, HD2000 graphics driver, and usb drivers? Also, when did this first start happening?

Comment: Assuming I have the PC for 24 months I think it's been doing it from month 2 or 3. But maybe it was random. I have never updated anything (bios, mobo chipset, usb drivers etc).

Comment: It's really hard to tell what the exact root cause is (it might get captured by the Windows Event logs but that's beyond me) but I think my suggestions should put you in the right direction for now. Is a fresh Windows 7 install an option?

Comment: Yes, of course its very hard to pinpoint what is going wrong. I was hoping that someone may have encountered this before. A fresh installation is not an option but I'll try upgrading what you mentioned.

Comment: I wish you the best of luck!